# which module of linux kernel can be loaded dynamic

Tags: linux-kernel

So, is there a list of the modules which are loadable?
Is the schedule module loadable?

my english is poor, maybe you know what I say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK , all drivers are loadable except platform drivers which are statically build with kernel. Core Kernel Modules are not loadable. so , Scheduler cannot loader dynamically.

Comment: Schedulers can be loaded dynamically

Comment: can you give more info about loading schedulers dynamically

Comment: For instance if you implement a new I/O scheduler you can simply insmod or modprobe it and then echo into the appropriate dev/sys file (I forget which) for your device to change the scheduler.